# The recipe says to cook in a slow cooker on medium setting for 5 hours (dry pasta cooking in last hour), but I only have low or high

Tags: pasta, slow-cooking, crockpot

I want to make a recipe that says to cook on medium setting for 5 hours, with the addition of dry pasta and cheese at the start of the last hour.  The recipe says to cook the ground beef before adding to slow cooker, so there's no raw meat to worry about. I'm concerned that if I put it on high, the (tomato-based) liquid will run too low to cook the pasta in the last hour.  Should I change from high to low every half hour?

Comment: There’s no standard for ‘medium’ heat in a slow cooker.  You may want to look for a similar recipe to see if they have instructions for ‘low’ or ‘high’. It’s also possible that they mean the middle setting, which is ‘low’ if the settings are warm/low/high

Comment: This sounds like something that can be started on high for an hour or so then switched to low for the rest.

Comment: tbh slow cookers don't usually evaporate much in 5 hours, even on high.

Comment: @Joe I'm not even sure how standard the usual settings are. Low seems quicker on my current one than my first, and the one in between (with a non stick metal inner pot) was quicker still. None of it enough to really matter for what I cook but noticeable

Comment: @ChrisH I suspect that many of them just put a constant amount of power into heating rather than trying to hold a specific temperature, so they’re more vague concepts rather than anything truly fixed.  And using a recipe intended for a smaller size crockpot could mean you end up cooking it at a higher temperature due to this

Comment: @Joe yes, fixed power is generally the case, in proportion to their size. The only time I follow a recipe with mine is Christmas pudding, all the mixed bean chilli, bean stew etc. I make just starts high and gets turned down when I reckon it's nearly done, if I started it a bit early to just leave on high